# How to display a Formula in a cell by passing a range in Sheets Google AppScripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

the problem that I face is this:
I have a formula (any, don't care).
I want display it in the same cell or in another cell 
without using the " before and after the range, but Sheets rise up the error below:

> Range not found

The code that I use is this:

```
 function formulaRif(reference) {
 var ref = '"'+reference+'"'; // se riesco a passare una stringa come indirizzo con le " aggiunte qui, mi svincolo dal doverle mettere tra le () della reference  nel foglio.
//return SpreadsheetApp . getActiveSpreadsheet() . getRange(reference) . getFormula(); 
//return ref;

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];

 var range = sheet.getRange(ref);

 return range.getFormula();
}
```

Passing reference without "" I could take advantage of the Sheets managing of formulas.

In other words when I move a formula, the range change automatically.

I hope that this is clear enough.

Thanks

E-

Comment: Your question needs some efforts to improve the editing, in particular you should improve the code format

Comment: Thanks, for yoyur reply, I'm new for this.
What do you mean with "you should improve the code format"?

Thanks

E-

Comment: What someone has done with your code snippet using CTRL + K (now your code is in a grey box)